# Bootstrap 3 Angular modal popup not processing touch events on mobile devices

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

Bootstrap3 and Angular are supposed to play nicely together.... and with Bootstrap being "mobile first" I never thought I'd run into this, but I have.

I have a modal window being popped up from a button (via a standard modalService), which works just fine across the desktop browsers I've tested with (IE 10, 11, Edge, Chrome, Opera, Safari, and Firefox) but fails on mobile.  Every mobile I have access to (IOS Chrome, IOS Safari, Android Internet Browser, and Android Chrome).

It also displays the same failure on Chrome emulation of mobile browsers.

In all cases on mobile, the radio buttons and checkbox fail to recognize a tap/click event.. unless I hold for a long long time (much longer than the 300ms I've seen mentioned in articles).  In a couple mobile browsers that do capture it - the Angular actions which result from the change are not being executed on the mobile clients (but are on the desktops)

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control"  ng-Model="modalOptions.rScope.selectedItem" name="purchase" ng-value="selectedItem=item" ngClick="modalOptions.rScope.selectedItem=item">
```

ngTouch is being added to the page to facilitate the faster ngClick event.

I have stripped out all the relevant code and created a plunk showing this :   http://plnkr.co/edit/iZV6JRnHHHRwAKO2JJ06

Is this a function of how the radio buttons were defined?  And if so, why is the checkbox displaying the same behaviour (I know it doesnt currently have an ngClick on it - but the behaviour is the same):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" width="20px" ng-model="modalOptions.rScope.xgiftfor" />
```

I get no errors indicating the ngTouch module is not being loaded...

The one thing that bothers me... the page for ngClick states:

> A more powerful replacement for the default ngClick designed to be used on 
>   touchscreen devices. Most mobile browsers wait about 300ms after a tap-and-
>   release before sending the click event. This version handles them immediately,
>   and then prevents the following click event from propagating.

Is ngTouch preventing Angular from continuing to propagate updates on the form? That click event will have other consequences as the **modalOption.rScope.selectedItem** update occurs.

OR am I stretching to find a reason for this behaviour?

[EDIT]

I have updated the plunk to display the same data set (code slightly modified due to scope) on the main page, and the behaviour on the modal is NOT present on the main page.  Run it in your fav desktop browser and it's good on the main page - but open the modal, and it just doesn't work.

http://embed.plnkr.co/WnxArMU9VUVjDwnvueV1

Does anyone have any clue what the modal introducing that is interfering with the processing (and how to work around it)?

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue 

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2017 and 

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11212


however the workarounds I've tried are not functioning.

I've ended up removing the <input type="radio"...> and replacing them with <button type="button"....> which function in the modal properly across all browsers that I can access.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact problem. Unfortunately, I only discovered that the [ngClick directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick) is now [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/13857) with no workaround.

> DEPRECATION NOTICE: Beginning with Angular 1.5, this directive is deprecated and by default disabled. The directive will receive no further support and might be removed from future releases. If you need the directive, you can enable it with the [$touchProvider#ngClickOverrideEnabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/provider/$touchProvider) function. We also recommend that you migrate to [FastClick](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/300-ms-click-delay-ios-8/). To learn more about the 300ms delay, this [Telerik article](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/300-ms-click-delay-ios-8/) gives a good overview.